# memory leak problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks

I'm new in iphone dev and in the deal of the memory issues. 
I'm learning but some things remain mysterious for me.

In the following case, the leaks analyzer of "Instruments" says I have a leak in the databasePath setting. I can't figure out why.

```
// databaseName and databasePath are properties of my class.
databaseName = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"sqlDbName.sql"];

NSArray *documentPaths = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)];

NSString *documentsDir = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[documentPaths objectAtIndex:0]];

// The problem is here : 
databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName]];

[documentPaths release];
[documentsDir release];
```

I release databaseName and databasePath later in the dealloc.

Your help will be very appreciate !

Comment: you mean you release `databasePath` and `databaseName` in your dealloc method right (your last paragraph says `databasePath` twice)?

Comment: In the dealloc I release databasePath and databaseName, that's right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there any possibility that this code is executing more than once. You have released `databasePath` in `dealloc`. In case this code is executed more than once then `databasePath` will leak for any successive execution.

Comment: YES !! You rule. The method was called twice. I fixed it and no more leaks appear. Thank you so much.

Comment: just a question : how to flag "Solve" my answer on this forum ?

Comment: tick box on the left side of the question you've chosen as the answer, just click it and it will turn green :)

Comment: @Pax, To accept an answer you need to click on the white tick mark just below the downvote arrow. It will turn to green.

Answer (score 1):

If you did want to have this method called twice,  you could do:

```
...
[databasePath release];
databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName]];
....
```

If `databasePath` was initially nil calling `[databasePath release];` will do nothing.

If `databasePath` was already initialized, it will release the old instance before assinging a new one.

Comment: Thank you, this will be helpful.